# Hide a texture in UV Editor

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

I'm planning to hide the texture of a certain object, but I can't seem to find the right tool.[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "hide the texture"?

Comment: I want to hide that encircled drawing in UV Editor. It causes some Error in projecting the design of what I have in photoshop. Here's the result in Blender 3D and in Photoshop, respectively. https://imgur.com/a/RtaMWPI

Comment: if you want to give this part another texture, create a new material, select this part of the mesh, and click Assign under the materials list